# Application get Crash while playing Video using MPMoviePlayerController Or Webview

Tags: ios, video, mpmovieplayercontroller, local

I'm unable to play video from locally. Application getting crash without displaying any error message in console.

Code is as below...

```
// Player..
            NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

            self.mpPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];
            [self.mpPlayer prepareToPlay];
            [self.mpPlayer play];

            //For viewing partially.....
            [self.mpPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
            [self.mpPlayer.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)];
            self.mpPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

            self.mpPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
            self.mpPlayer.fullscreen = NO;
            self.mpPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
            [self.mpPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
            self.mpPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

            [self addSubview:self.mpPlayer.view];



// Webview

            NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];

            NSURLRequest *request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:videoURL];

            UIWebView *webView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
            [webView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)];
            [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Please let me know, If i'm doing any wrong code.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like this :

```
NSURL* videoURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:videoPath];
self.mpPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:videoURL];

[self.mpPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, imageWidth, imageHeight)];
[self.mpPlayer.view setCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2)];
self.mpPlayer.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor grayColor];

        self.mpPlayer.repeatMode = MPMovieRepeatModeOne;
        self.mpPlayer.fullscreen = NO;
        self.mpPlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeFile;
        [self.mpPlayer setControlStyle:MPMovieControlStyleNone];
        self.mpPlayer.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFit;

        [self addSubview:self.mpPlayer.view];


 [self.mpPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is resolved, Actually it was due to exception break point. I removed it and it's working now.